# Secant Method : number of steps

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I want to estimate the number of steps needed by the secant method to approximate the root of a function $f$ with a given tolerance. I stop the algorithm when the distance between 2 consecutive root approximations is less than the given tolerance.

I assume that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, the root in question is simple and initial values are *close enough* to the root.

Is there a simple formula that gives the number of steps needed?

Comment: That depends on the stopping criterion, doesn't it? Also on how close the initial point is to a root

Comment: I stop when the distance between 2 consecutive root aproximations is less than a given tolerance.

Comment: it is better to edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sequence of secant steps converges, then the asymptotic convergence velocity is the golden mean, $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$.

Thus to get get precision $\varepsilon$ you get from
$$
\|x_n-x_*\|\sim \|x_1-x_0\|^{ϕ^n}\implies \log\|x_n-x_*\|\sim ϕ^n\log\|x_1-x_0\|
$$
that
$$
n\approx \frac{\log|\logε|-\log|\log\|x_1-x_0\||}{\log ϕ}
$$

In an actual formula, there would be some constants for the bounds of the derivatives involved, for simple examples these should not contribute much.

---

With $$ε_n\le C^{-1}(Cε_0)^{ϕ^n}$$ (with $ε_n$ being the error magnitude of $\|x_n-x_*\|$ and $\|x_n-x_{n+1}\|$) as a more exact formula you get the problem of estimating $C$ from, for instance $C^{ϕ-1}=ε_1/ε_0$ or $C=(ε_1/ε_0)^ϕ$ should at least get the magnitude right so that 
$$
\log(Cε_n)\approx ϕ^n\log(Cε_0)\implies \log|\log(Cε_n)|\approx n\logϕ+\log|\log(Cε_0)|
$$
etc.

Comment: What if $|x_1 - x_0| > 1$ ?

Comment: This is what the remark about constants is about. The error estimate starts with $ε_{n+1}\le Cε_{n}ε_{n-1}$ where $C$ contains bounds for first and second derivatives, so that in the logarithm $\log(Cε_{n+1})\le \log(Cε_{n})+\log(Cε_{n-1})$ which looks like the Fibonacci recursion.